# In first class method included second class. I wanna use first class parent protected method in second class

Tags: php, oop

I have a structure which I can't change.

Here is a example

File 1

```
class a
{
    protected function query(){}
}

class b extends a
{
    public function show()
    {
        include "File 2"
    }
}
```

File 2

```
class c
{
    public function someFunction()
    {           
        //Here I wanna use query method
    }
}
```

I can extends b class for c. Is it right way?

Comment: *"I can extends b class for c. Is it right way?"* -- let the code apart and try to answer the real question: what is the relationship between `a` and `c`? Does it make sense for an object of type `c` to also be an object of type `a`? If the answer is "yes" then let class `c` extend class `a`. If the answer is "no" then answer the next question: does it make sense for an object of type `c` to have a property of type `a`? If the answer is "yes" then create in class `c` a property of type `a`. If the answer is "no" then stop here and redesign your classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will be right way if you want to use all public and protected methods of `Class b` in class c.

Else you can directly extend class c from `class a` to use protected function `query` of class a.

Comment: Hope this answer is helpful to you. Are you following it?

Comment: extend your class like this: class c extendes class a